# Find highest column in row PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am triying to read all columns from an excel file but its number is variable depending on the row. For example:
Row1, col2, col3, col4
Row2, col2,col3
Row3,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6

I am trying to do something like:

```
for ($row = 1; $row < 2; $row++){
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                    NULL,
                                    TRUE,
                                    FALSE);
    echo print_r($rowData[0][0]);
    echo "<br>";
    $list_of_coordinates = "";
    $i = 1;
    //echo print_r($rowData[$row][$i+1]);
    while($rowData[0][$i+1] != ""){
      /*$list_of_coordinates = $list_of_coordinates . 
                             "," .
                             $rowData[0][$i+1] . 
                             "," .
                             $rowData[0][$i];
      */
      $i+2;
    }
    $list_of_coordinates = ltrim($list_of_coordinates, ",");
    echo $list_of_coordinates;
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

But the $highestcolumn has the column number of the maximum one, in this file: BM. But some of the rows have just 3 or 4 columns. Is it possible to update this number? MY while loop is not working right now.

Comment: We need Mark Baker on this Topic, he is Guru of PHPExcel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getHighestColumn()` and `getHighestDataColumn()` methods accept an optional row number as an argument. If called without passing any argument, they will return the highest column number in the worksheet; but if called with a row number, they will return the highest column in the specified row.

However, as an alternative, you could use the row and column iterators, for existing cells only (see `28iterator.php` in `/Examples`).

Comment: I could make it work with that example. Thank you Mark