# How to get particular row's column count in PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

Im working in codeigniter framework for reading excel sheet datas im using **PHPExcel** library.

So, In my controller im calling the PHPExcel library function like below :

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($targetFile);
$data = $reader->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$totalrows = $data->getHighestDataRow();
```

Im getting datas of excel sheet. Im iterating to get particular column values. I want to get each rows column count.

```
for($i=2; $i<=$totalrows; $i++){
    // Here i want to get total column count or column name like A or B
    $worksheet->getCellRow($i)->getValue(); // this way i tried but its not working
}
```

Comment: I found answer here [Find highest column in row PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35268686/6624737)